# Two onblur for same input id

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is my routine. i need to do two onblur function at a mean time. below code works exact when there is single onblur. how can i modify my code to achieve both functionality.

HTML coding:

```
<input type="text" name="frmEmail" id="frmEmail" class="textbox" value="Email Address" onfocus="if(this.value =='Email Address'){this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Email Address'}"  />
```

Javascript coding:

```
function checkEmpty()
{
    count=0;
    if(document.getElementById('frmEmail').value=="Email Address") {
        document.getElementById('frmEmail').style.backgroundColor = '#f6a9ae';
        count++;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('frmEmail').style.backgroundColor = '';
    }

    if(count!=0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What has this question to do with CSS? Why are you returning a boolean to the bit space?

Comment: What do you mean by "mean time"?

Comment: that is same time brother :)

Comment: It looks like you want to have the beaviour the `placeholder` attribute is giving you. Is there a reason you are not using it? (works with IE10+). For your problem, you could use `object.addEventListener("blur",function(){ /*more than one action*/  });`

Comment: just for form submission.. incase if the textbox contains the value "Email Address" and meanwhile i click submit button, the current form shouldn't have to submit.. thats why i written boolean action... @Teemu

Comment: `blur` is not cancelable, nor returning a boolean from its handler doesn't affect form submitting.

Answer (score 2):

Create a 'parent' function that calls subroutines.

`<input ... onblur="myparent();">`

```
function myparent(){
   dothis();
   dothat();
}
```

A better solution is to create a listener to the event, instead of sticking a handler inline, such as

**jQuery method:**

```
 <input id="myel">
$(function(){
 $("#myel").blur(function() { 
   dothis(); 
   dothat(); 
 });
});
```

Or, the **non-jQuery** required way with pure JS:

```
 <input id="myel">

 var myel = document.getElementById("myel");
 myel.onblur = function() { 
    dothis(); 
    dothat(); 
 }
```

Comment: Are you using jquery library?  The above 2nd syntax requires it.

Comment: @SyedIbrahim i've updated my answer to include a non-jQuery way as well.

Answer (score 1):

apply this code

```
<input type="text" name="frmEmail" id="frmEmail" class="textbox" value="Email Address" 
    onfocus="if(this.value =='Email Address'){this.value=''; this.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';}" 
    onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Email Address'} checkEmpty()"  />
```

Comment: It partially works brother.. but background color didn't change while i press tab..