# Can't focus an input after "onblur"

Tags: javascript, php

I have three simple texts and I want to make a validation on "onblur" of the second text. It should delete the content just typed and keep focusing on the same input. I can make it delete the content, but it doesn't focus. What could be happening?

```js
function validate() {
  document.getElementById("txt-second").value = "";
  document.getElementById("txt-second").focus();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt-first" />
<input type="text" id="txt-second" onblur="validate();" />
<input type="text" id="txt-third" />
```

Comment: Seems to be working just fine in Chrome on MacOS. Could you tell more about the environment you are testing this in (browser, OS)?

Comment: Hello Emiel, I'm testing in Mozilla Firefox 69.0 (Windows 10 - 64). I think it works in chrome.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this code snippet?

Comment: basically I need a sequence of "valid numbers" into the second input, if this sequence is correct I can go to the next input, else, I need to clear the second input and focus on it again to type the right sequence. But, It also shoud I leave the second input if user doesnt know the right sequence.

Comment: I would suggest to not do the validation on `onblur`. Because you would not be able to leave the focus of the field. Instead use the `onchange` or `oninput` events to check the validity.

Answer (score 0):

Strange that onblur doesn't work for me either.

```
<input type="text" id="txt-first"/>
<input type="text" id="txt-second"/>
<input type="text" id="txt-third"/>

<script>
function validate(event){
  this.value = "";
  this.focus();
}

var txtSeconds = document.getElementById("txt-second");
txtSeconds.onblur = validate;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a 'parent' function that has subroutines

```
<script>
var ele = document.getElementById("txt-second");
ele.onblur = function(){
   ele.value="";
   ele.focus();
}
</script>
```

If that doesnt work out, checkout this question [Two onblur for same input id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25531718/two-onblur-for-same-input-id)

Edit: I just tested your code out and it worked for me, problem is once it focuses I can't get the cursor out of that input box...